# How to synchronise data from different modules Redis

Tags: redis, redisgraph, redisjson

I am new to redis and I wanted to know if there was a way to synchronise my data from my redisJson and my redisGraph

For example, I have a user un a hash or a redisJson and I have this same user in my redisGraph

How do I synchronise this user everywhere so that when I change is email in the hash it changes every where.

I know that this exists for mongoDb and neo4j, there must be something similar for Redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RedisGears][1] to register on any JSON change and synchronously update the Graph accordingly.

See a similar example that listen to Hash changes and update the graph accordingly: https://github.com/RedisGears/MultiModelExample

You can also see more examples here:
https://oss.redis.com/redisgears/examples.html

[1]: https://oss.redis.com/redisgears/